# adding negative statement to regex

Tags: php, regex, tel

I am trying to check if a phone number like this exists in using regex.

> (001) 33992292

So, I used

```
if(preg_match("/[0-9\(\)]+/", $row)){
     //is phone number
  }
```

But, the problem with this is that, strings containing numbers get passed as well, like `foo134@yahoo.com`, so how can I evaluate a phone number and exclude `@` character is strings all together?

Comment: You need to use anchors (see a regex tutorial) and to describe all the string.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte why should I use anchor? what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UDPATED**
`/^(\(\d+\))*\s?(\d+\s*)+$/`

you missed start string `^` sign and end string `$` sign, what else your regex is wrong
because 5545()4535 will also pass match

Comment: try it now I missed space

Comment: Same thing. I can't even have a simple tel number to show up

Comment: ahh you pass full row, not just phone number? what is your input in this case `$row`, also you can test it on https://www.regex101.com/

Comment: `$row` is just a row of numbers from database. They are not arrays, they are all tel numbers. Some mixed with string, so I just wanted to see only the clean numbers. example. `(001) 33445566` ...

Comment: Nope, Not even close.  just arrays with keys and values, null and nothing more.

Comment: Obviously your data is way different.

Comment: This seemed to work for me, `if(preg_match("/^[0-9\(\)]+/", $row){...}` I just had to add `^`

Comment: Updated regex, test it... you didn't tell us between phone number is so many spaces

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [**anchors**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#caret) in your regular expression, a proper syntax would be:

```
if(preg_match('~^\(\d{3}\) *\d{8}$~', $row)) { ... }
```

Comment: I just have a number like this. `(001) 33992292`

Comment: I don't understand. My approach at-least returns the tel number, but mistakes string that contain numbers as well, whereas yours, shows me none

Comment: There is no error in the regex I provided, perhaps your data. See here: https://eval.in/281136

Answer (score 1):

Telephone numbers are notorious for people to get wrong - and by people I mean programmers.

For example, these are all "common" ways of writing a phone number:

```
(001) 33992292
001 33992292
00133992292
001 3399 2292
(001) 3399-2292
```

A saner approach it to just remove everything that isn't a number and check the length:

```
$phonenumber = "(001) 33992292";
$phonenumber = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $phonenumber );

if (strlen($phonenumber) == 11) {
    // do thing
}
```